# How can I display data from mysql database using DataGrid in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

My background is in PHP / MySQL, but I am currently attempting to learn how to use ASP.Net with MySQL. I have created a small application that allows users to add a task. I am trying to retrieve the full list of tasks when a button is pressed. At one point, I was getting a result where by about half of the first row was displaying and nothing else (taskid & createdate). That is no longer showing up and I don't know why.

Would anyone have any advice or information that might help me to resolve this issue?

You can view the application at www.galtechsolutions.net/tasklist

My Markup is:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="viewtasks.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyTasks.ViewTasks" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<link href="style.css" rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" />
<title>TaskList - View Tasks</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="default.aspx">Home</a> | <a href="addtask.aspx">Add Task</a> | <a href="viewtasks.aspx">View Tasks</a>
<br /><br />
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="gettasks" runat="server" Text="Show Tasks" class="taskbutton" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGridView1" runat="server" PageSize="5" AllowPaging="True" 
        DataKeyField="taskid" AllowSorting="True" 
        EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="taskid" DataField="taskid"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="createdate" DataField="createdate"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="taskname" DataField="taskname="></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="taskdesc" DataField="taskdesc"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="duedate" DataField="duedate"></asp:BoundColumn>
    </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>      
    <asp:Label ID="gettaskslabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My code behind is:

```
Protected Sub gettasks_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gettasks.Click

    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    Dim selcmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim SQL As String

    conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=phaspdev1.db.10654019.hostedresource.com;Database=phaspdev1;User Id=;Password=;")
    selcmd = New MySqlCommand

    Try
        conn.Open()
        SQL = "SELECT * FROM mytasks"
        selcmd.Connection = conn
        selcmd.CommandText = SQL

        dtadapter.SelectCommand = selcmd
        dtadapter.Fill(dt)


        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.DataBind()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Columns.Add("taskid", GetType(Integer))
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Columns.Add("createdate", GetType(Date))
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Columns.Add("taskname", GetType(String))
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Columns.Add("taskdesc", GetType(String))
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Columns.Add("duedate", GetType(Date))

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)

        Next dr
        dt.AcceptChanges()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect to database: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Comment: Why are you using the old `DataGrid` control and not a `GridView`? Are you still on ASP.NET 1.1? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163933.aspx

Comment: I tried to use your code to recreate problem. And got several errors. Can you post full code behind class ?

Comment: Just want to say a quick thanks to those who responded to this question. Their suggestions, advice, and help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting autoeventwireup to true.  It sounds like you don't have your event handler set on the button.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup.aspx